# I have a class and I want to know When my classes are deactivating?

Tags: flutter

I have a class and I want to know when my class leave my tree widget. I think I can do that with lifecycle of app but I don't know how to do that.
please help

Answer (score 1):

in StatefullWidget there is a method name deactivate just call that method and place your code in it which will execute when widget is deactivated from widget tree

```
@override
void deactivate() {
  log('Deactivated');
  // TODO : Place your code here which will execute at deactivation
  super.deactivate();
}
```